# stringify JSON reference name, not the referenced object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object like so, (this is an example)

```
house.keys = {
    "key1" : "23456",
    "key2" : "97543",
    "key3" : "35493"
}
house.doors = [{
        "name" : "Front door",
        "lock key" : house.keys.key1
    }, {
        "name" : "Back door",
        "lock key" : house.keys.key2
    }
]
```

This object is stored in the DB as a string, and read and `parsed()` on page load.  It will likely be edited by user interaction, then the altered object needs to be `stringify()`-ed and written back into DB.  I've got everything working except for a problem in the `stringify()` function.

Instead of this:

```
"lock key" : house.keys.key1
```

I get this:

```
"lock key" : "23456"
```

How do I get the `stringify()` method to return the referenced object's name instead of the referenced object, itself.

I've looked into using a replacer function:

```
JSON.stringify(house, replacer);  // Where replacer() returns 'something else' for "lock key", but I don't know what 'something else' is.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just wrap it in quotes

Comment: `"lock key" : house.keys.key1` that's not JSON. The correct JSON string would need to be `"lock key" : "house.keys.key1"`

Comment: `stringify` isn't doing this. It's happening when you do the assignment. Property values are evaluated in object literals. By the time you call stringify, the original name is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just enclose the name in quotes so that it will be treated as a string and therefore, the value will not be parsed and put.

```
 house.doors = [{
     "name": "Front door",
     "lock key": "house.keys.key1"
 }, {
     "name": "Back door",
     "lock key": "house.keys.key2"
 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

This does appear to be the best solution to my problem.  It did require a change to the code that was using the 'house' object.

Before, I was referencing the key as such:
`var key1 = house.doors[0]["lock key"];`

Now I have to use:

`var key1 = house.doors[0]["lock key"];
var key1 = eval(key1);`

(I believe I've written this right.  My actual code is considerably different.)

All in all, an easier fix then the other solutions I was contemplating.